# JavaScript runtime error: in IE only

Tags: javascript

Am getting an error when i run my site in IE (local host)

the error is as follows:

**Unhandled exception at line 1440, column 9 in eval code**

**0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference**

**If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.**

This is the code it goes to:

```
 $window.scroll(function () {
```

> if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {

```
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});
```

the highlighted code is where it keeps hitting when i scroll on the page.

Am not sure why this is happening, has this happened to anyone? Or any ideas why its doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have got confused between **offset.top** with **window.top**
just review your code once again. And try replacing your 'offset.top' with 'window.top'

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the error message:

*"Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference"*

That means that whatever you're trying to get `top` from, is `undefined` or `null`.
Specifically: `offset` is.

Comment: what do you mean by offset

Comment: @ma32112345: `offset.top`, you wrote that in the question. Do you have a clean idea of what that script is actually doing?

Comment: oh. when making my screens this page called eval code popped up with the error message. hmm

Comment: What I meant is that `offset` is either `null` or `undefined`, as the error message clearly said.